# deploy scrapy in a remote machine

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Hello I am using scrapy and I have managed to deploy it with scrapyd - this work perfectly in my localhost but when it comes to run it from another computer it doesn't work out.

this command works fine : 
`curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=webplode -d` `spider=pingwebsite -d file=./testfiles/testfiles.xlsx`

but when it come to run this one :

`curl http://myip:6800/schedule.json -d project=webplode -d` `spider=pingwebsite -d file=./testfiles/testfiles.xlsx`

I get the following error msg :

`Failed to connect to myip port 6800: Connection refused`

here is my scrapy.cfg

```
# Automatically created by: scrapy startproject
#
# For more information about the [deploy] section see:
# https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy.html

[settings]
default = webplode.settings

[deploy:local]
url = http://myip:6800/
project = webplode
```

I don't find scrapyd.conf, I am running this on windows

Comment: Can you check if scrapyd is running correctly on the remote server? (f.e. `sudo service scrapyd status` on Ubuntu)

Comment: I am deploy it on windows

Comment: ok - can you check whether scrapyd is running on the windows server? and make sure port 6800 is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manage to solve my problem, I just have to change the settings of my **scraper** and add my ip address like below:

scrapy.cfg :

```
[settings]
default = webplode.settings

[scrapyd]
bind_address= myip

[deploy:local]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = webplode
```